# Mockito NullPointer Exception for the method called on Mock Object

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am getting a NPE when the first when(creditApplicationCache.getObject("")).thenRetun(response) is called. creditApplicationCache is null.

1. I am using mockito 2.17.jar.
2. I have added the @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class).
3. I have also tried with MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this).

But nothing has helped. CreditApplicationCache is not getting initialized.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class WebServiceClientTest {
    
    @InjectMocks
    WebServiceClientImpl webServiceClientImpl;
    
    @Mock
    private ApplicationCacheImpl creditApplicationCache;
        
    /*@Before
    public void setUp()  {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }*/

    @Test
    public void testWebServiceClient() throws BusinessException, SystemException {
        WebServiceClientImpl webServiceClientImpl = new WebServiceClientImpl();         
        
        CreditCardDetailsResponse creditCardDetailsResponse = new CreditCardDetailsResponse();
        creditCardDetailsResponse.setAccountNumber("1234567");
        
when(creditApplicationCache.getObject("XXXXXXX")).thenReturn(creditCardDetailsResponse);         
 when(webServiceClientImpl.getCreditCardDetails("1234")).thenReturn(creditCardDetailsResponse);
        CreditCardDetailsResponse mockResponse = webServiceClientImpl.getCreditCardDetails("1234");
            
        assertEquals(creditCardDetailsResponse.toString(),mockResponse.toString());             
    }
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebServiceClientImpl.java

public class WebServiceClientImpl implements WebServiceClient {
@Autowired
private ApplicationCache creditApplicationCache;

public CreditCardDetailsResponse getCreditCardDetails(String id)
            throws BusinessException, SystemException {
        // Some Code
    CreditCardDetailsResponse response = null;
        
        response = (CreditCardDetailsResponse) creditApplicationCache.getObject(cacheKey);
        if (response == null) {
            try {
             // More Code }
    return response ;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating the client again on the first line of the test: `WebServiceClientImpl webServiceClientImpl = new WebServiceClientImpl();`

`@InjectMocks` already constructs the annotated class, and injects all the relevant mocks, but what you do is re-create it without it, hence the NPE.

Simply remove that line and it should work

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occur, when you import `@Test` from `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead of `org.junit.Test`. Can you ensure, that you are using the correct `@Test` annotation?